# conda ROS gazebo ardupilot gazebo

Tags: cmake, conda, ros, apple-silicon, gazebo-simu

I use mac os m1. I installed anaconda and I create an envoirement ROS. I installed ROS, and gazebo was installed ROS. so I did not do anything to install gazebo. because after ros installing gazebo is ready. I want to use ardupilot_gazebo. and I looked this website https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/sitl-with-gazebo.html . step 1 is instaling SITL. I have install SITL. and it can be run. after running SITL ı opened Qgroundcontrol. and they are connected automaticly. I want to connect gazebo to SITL. I install ardupilot_gazebo pulgins. and I try this step:

```
cd ardupilot_gazebo
mkdir build && cd build
```

there is no problem.

however when ı try

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

I take this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgz-cmake3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "gz-cmake3", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gz-cmake3" with
  any of the following names:

    gz-cmake3Config.cmake
    gz-cmake3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gz-cmake3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gz-cmake3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "gz-cmake3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

and I think there is not gazebo in ROS enviroment in my mac. however I write gazebo in terminal in ROS enviroment, gazebo is opned. I saw this code `gz sim -v4 -r shapes.sdf` to check gazebo in the website. and ı write to ROS. and ı saw

```
(ROS) halitsen@halit-MacBook-Air build % gz sim -v4 -r shapes.sdf
Invalid arguments
(ROS) halitsen@halit-MacBook-Air build %
```

however, there is gazebo in ROS.
I think that there is gazebo but I installed it with ros. when cmake search gazebo to connect SITL, it cannot find gazebo because of gazebo was installed with ROS.

How to can I solve this problem?

I tried connect gazebo and SITL and Qgroundcontrol with anaconda environment in macbook air m1 chip.

Answer (score 0):

To check gazebo you can try `gazebo /usr/share/gazebo/worlds/shapes.world`

The command may look as: `gazebo full/path/to/the/shapes.world`